# execute jquery in asp.net

Tags: jquery

How does this work?

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //$.blockUI();
        //select from DB;
        //$.unblockUI();
    }
```

Thanks From Allllll

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you asking how to trigger server-side code using jQuery or are you asking how to stub out the function above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, it doesn't work.  JavaScript code (hence, jQuery code) executes in the browser on the client-side.  .NET (ASP) code executes on the server-side.  They can interact in varying ways, but not in this way.  You can't write JavaScript code in a C# method as in your example.

What, specifically, are you trying to accomplish?  I see that you're trying to run JavaScript code in your C# method, sure, but for what purpose?  Usually one attempts this as a result of not fully understanding the page life cycle and how/when different things get executed.  What's the end goal here?

Comment: tanks. do not way that execute jquery function in c# method.

Comment: @ashkufaraz: I'm afraid there's a significant language barrier here.  Based on other comments, it really sounds like you're unfamiliar with the technology in question here.  If you need further help with this, we're happy to provide it.  But clarity is going to be key.

Answer (score 0):

You should clarify your question. But if you want to know how to fetch server side data through javascript (ajax) using jquery, you should take a look at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I Like Execute Jquery Function In Asp Mehtod

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify regarding the scenario in which you are using this?
As I can understand, when user clicks a button, you black out the screen, fetch some results from the DB and when you have to show stuff back on the UI, you remove the black out.. Right?

If that is so, then you can do like this -

1. in the aspx page, use OnClientClick property of the button to specify a javascript function. Lets call it 'JSButtonClick'.
2. In this, function you call $.blockUI();
3. Also, make a ajax call to the server side. Use [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).
   To call page behind you will have to define a public static function with the attribute [WebMethod] -> System.Web.Services.
4. In the page behind function, do your DB call and stuff.
5. Return the Db results serialised in JSON. Use JavascriptSerialiser (System.Web.Script.Serialization)
6. Then in the success of ajax, you show your result and do $.unblockUI();

Its gonna be little problem if you want to update some GridView or something :)

Comment: tanks. but i do not like use jquery ajax . i like run all code in protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 1.$blockui 2.select from DB 3.$.unblock() . without use jquery ajax and json.

Comment: I dont want to disappoint you but the fact is that it is not possible. You may use ClientRegisterScript method of ASP.Net if you want. 

Also, when you click a button, it will fire a postback and even if you are able to black out things, it will vanish and page will load afresh. So, your purpose wont get solved that way also.

Comment: tanks. do not way that run jqery function in c# method